# Creating a push function for linked stack program?

Tags: java

here some code of my linked stack program:

```
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

class linkstack<T> {

   private class node {
      T value;
      node link;
   }

   private node top = null;

          ...
```

Now, my push function header is this:

```
public void push (T value) {
      node temp = new node();
      temp.value =

 }
```

Im planning on assigning the value of temp to equal the value thats being passed in the parameter of the push method but Im not sure if I can do that because I'm not sure what "T" is exactly?

Also I have written a pop function, does this make any sense? :

```
public T pop() {
      if (empty()) {
         throw new NoSuchElementException ("linked_stack.pop");
      } else{
         node temp = top;
         temp = top.link;
         return temp.value;

      }
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the generic type of `node`, not the raw type, ie:

```
 private class Node<T> {
     ...
   }

public void push (T value) {
      Node<T> temp = new Node();
      temp.value = value;
 }
```

For an introduction to generics, check out this [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/).  For a more advanced reference, check out [Anjelika Langer's Java Generics FAQ](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html).

Comment: Thank You! But can you also explain, what exactly is the purpose of <T>? what does that mean?

Comment: @AayushK Unfortunately, that's not a simple question to answer.  Here, check out this [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/).  Basically, `T` stands for an object type (NB: object **not** primitive, so `int` won't work, you would need to use `Integer`).  After you finish the tutorial, if you have anymore questions, I suggest asking more questions or trying to find some examples online.  This is a little advanced for you right now, but in the future, this [Generics Reference](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html) could be valuable.

Comment: Can u check the pop function Ive written and let me know if its right because I'm unsure of the temp = top.link

Comment: @AayushK This is a completely different question that requires more code than is presented; however, what I know is wrong is that you're using the raw type of `node` again, instead of `Node<T>`.  If you test it and it doesn't work, I suggest that you ask a new question.